# PHP-JSON : How can I Pass json into my javascript code (jschart)?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a short problem. I want to pass my `json` into the `javascript` code ?

I use js charts.
    My code in `PHP` like this :

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            var chart;
            var legend;

            var chartData = [{
                country: "france",
                value: 260},
            {
                country: "belgique",
                value: 500},
            {
                country: "canada",
                value: 65},
            {
                country: "italie",
                value: 39},
            {
                country: "cameroun",
                value: 19},
            {
                country: "brasil",
                value: 10}];

            AmCharts.ready(function() {
                // PIE CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.titleField = "country";
                chart.valueField = "value";
                chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
                chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
                chart.outlineThickness = 2;
                // this makes the chart 3D
                chart.depth3D = 15;
                chart.angle = 30;

                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });
            </script>';
?>
```

When I print my json file :

```
[["@brasil","5"],["@italy","5"],["@france","1"],["@belgique","5"],["@canada","5"],["@cameroun","1"],["@spain","5"]]
```

How can I proceed ??

Comment: It should already work like this.

Comment: How can I replace country:"italie",value:39,etc... by my json which contain [["@brasil","5"],["@italy","5"],["@france","1"],["@belgique","5"],["@canada","5"],["@cameroun","1"],["@spain","5"]]